# Variable en Arreglo de objetos

Tags: javascript

antes que nada un saludo.
Mi detalle es el siguiente obtengo por medio de ajax datos que pongo en unas variables que son las siguientes

```
        var cveProd = info.Resultado.cveProducto;
        var descVal = info.Resultado.DesValor;
        var hola  = [{idclave: CveProd , descc: descVal }];
```

en hola quiero ponerlas como un arreglo de objetos PERO recibo esto

```
[{"idclave": [" AL-32021611 "," AL-32021612 ", " AL-32021612 ", " AL-32021612 "],
"descc":["7500","Continental","Piso R3","7500"]}]
```

y me es complicado por que necesito algo como esto y no se me ocurre como hacerlo

```
var hola= [
{
    idclave: "AL-32021612",
    descc: "7500"    },

{
    idclave: "AL-32021612",
    descc: "Continental"    },

{
    idclave: "AL-32021612",
    descc: "Piso R3"    },

{
    idclave: "AL-32021612"
    descc: "7500",
         }];
```

gracias por leerme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con la siguiente solución, si los arreglos tienen distinto largo, van a quedar elementos afuera. Además, se parte del supuesto que los arreglos vienen en el orden correcto, lo cual depende de tu backend.

Con esas salvedades, puedes probar esto:

```js
    var cveProd = [" AL-32021611 "," AL-32021612 ", " AL-32021612 ", " AL-32021612 "];
    var descVal = ["7500","Continental","Piso R3","7500"];
    var hola  = [];
    var largo_arreglos=Math.min(cveProd.length, descVal.length);
    
    for(var i=0;i<largo_arreglos;i++) {
      hola.push({idclave: cveProd[i], descc: descVal[i] });
    }
    console.log(hola);
```

Comment: si vienen en orden correcto y pues cada cve producto viene forzosamente con un descVal asi que no puede quedar impar, gracias!!!